# How to continue change things while screen is locked? Android Java

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mp3, spinner

Hello guys i have a page where i play an mp3 file according to an object in spinner in details:

- if the selected item in spinner is 1 then the file with name 1 will
  be played
- when the file ends i want to automatically change the spinner selected object and continue to play the next file

the problem is when the screen is locked the selected object at spinner won't change. can anyone help me?

Comment: Assuming you have a list of ids you could update the UI from the `onResume()` method. Get the currently playing file from media player instance then populate the spinner with that item.

Comment: after using onResume() method to update UI the mediaplayer continues where it was but it creates a second instance of the same mediaplayer, so i hear  the same thing twice with 2 second between each instance!